# Find occurrences of strings from unstructured text file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text

Is there any automatic way to do that in matlab?

Comment: What do you mean with unstructured text file? Can you give an example?

Comment: Take a look at this link http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/3981-string-search-and-delete-in-txt-file

Comment: Do you want to find _where_ the string occurs in a file, or just _if_ it occurs?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like strfind is what you're looking for for the search
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strfind.html

```
FID = fopen(FileName, 'rb');
str= fread(FID, [1, inf], 'char');
fclose(FID);
found = strfind(word, str)
```

Found will have the indices of word.

Hope that is closer to what you wanted.

Comment: Note: findstr will be removed in a future release. Use [strfind](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/strfind.html) instead.

Comment: No. this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Now, this approximates what I am looking for. But, let's see how we can make it work. How can we use this built-in function in order to extract occurrences of each word within an unstructured ASCII text?

Comment: @Eric At the moment, it doesn't work at all. How could we compute the occurrences?

Comment: I'm going to need more detail than that to help. What did you do, what happened, what did you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has powerful mechanism to handle strings, see [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) for more details.

You can read the entire file into memory, and search it using `regexp`, for example:

```
txt = fileread( fileName );
tokens = regexp( txt, str, 'tokens' );
```